# How to "grant create user" after enabling Oracle Vault

Tags: oracle, oracle-vault

I need Oracle Vault for SSL database connection. After installing it, the "system" user is not allowed to create database users. How to grant the "create user" privilege to system after installing Vault or create another user with that privilege? I tried to login as Vault Admin and "grant create user" - got a "realm violation". Granting the privilege via the "em" web interface didn't solve the issue - sqlplus still complains on insufficient privileges when trying to "create user". Please help without redirecting me to the Vault documentation - it is unreadable (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

> This is the default configuration of Database Vault.
>
> Only DV manager can create users and grant them the create session privilege ( or
>   connect role ). SYSDBA can grant system privileges as before.
>
> However, There is a Realm called: Oracle System Privilege and Role Management Realmand only SYS is authorized as OWNER in it.   You can authorize a new user in that realm to be able to grant privileges outside of SYS :
>
> ```
> BEGIN
> DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
>   realm_name   => 'Oracle System Privilege and Role Management Realm', 
>   grantee      => 'DEBEA', 
>   auth_options => DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_OWNER);
> END;
> /
> ```

Referenced from : Oracle Community